# Apache SSL FS disable SHA1

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ssl

I am using apache 2.2.15 and are about to make it as secure as possible.
When I do a scan of one of my websites via the Qualys SSL Test.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

It lists me the following cipher suits:

`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256`

I somehow want to get rid of the thid line with `_SHA`, because this should be covered by the above line (2nd) with `_SHA384`.

I have the following vhost configuration:

`SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AES256GCM:AES256+EECDH`

How should I change `SSLCipherSuite` to get rid of the last `_SHA` line?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother.

See [Why is HMAC-SHA1 still considered secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/why-is-hmac-sha1-still-considered-secure)

Don't confuse the use of SHA1 as a certificate-signing algorithm (which [is insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#The_SHAppening)) with the use of SHA1 in a cipher suite's HMAC.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Is it however still possible to get rid of it somehow?

Comment: @lockdoc *Is it however still possible to get rid of it somehow?* Go here:  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/  Get a configuration that explicitly lists the cipher suites, then remove the ones you don't want.  Your version of OpenSSL matters, too, assuming you're using OpenSSL.  You should probably disable TLSv1, also.  TLSv1 is likely a lot more vulnerable than using a SHA1-HMAC cipher suite.